# SELECT all from specific table and handle foreach row

Tags: php

I stuck in some code here E.G:

Database table :

```
IMG_ID|IMG_SRC|EXPIRES|ACTION
------------------------------
 4    | st.jpg |12546564| temp
```

So i try to delete the image from DB and from directory path so far i got this :

```
function removeTempPic(){       
    $uploadsDirectory1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'test/uploads/temp/';  
    //remove after 10 minute if unused
    $timeout = time()-TEMPIC_TIMEOUT*60;
    $q = "SELECT * FROM picsmanager WHERE expires < $timeout AND action=temp";
    mysql_query($q, $this->connection);

    foreach ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $q = "delete * from picsmanager where=??"
       //@unlink($uploadsDirectory1.$uploadFilename);
    }
}
```

So what i try to do is select all from database table , and where timeout expire in some row delete each image from db and from directory
But this wont work because i dont know how to make it properly , Thanks.

Comment: change to `action = 'temp'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have multiple errors, in PHP and SQL

```
// enclose the string "temp" in single quotes
$q = "SELECT * FROM picsmanager WHERE expires < $timeout AND action='temp'";
$result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
// you need the result, not $q again
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   // run a new query to delete the extracted image
   mysql_query("delete from picsmanager where IMG_ID=" . $row['IMG_ID'] . " LIMIT 1", $this->connection);
   // delete the corresponding file
   unlink($uploadsDirectory1.$row['IMG_SRC']);
}
```

Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are becoming deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future. Your code will stop working then. Learn how to use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects.

Comment: Thanks allot,working like charm . just unlink not working i will play with that untill it will work,and thx for tips i know i need to change to mysqli but no time to learn it now i need to rush with some script. thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function removeTempPic(){

  $uploadsDirectory1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'test/uploads/temp/';  

  //remove after 10 minute if unused
  $timeout = time()-TEMPIC_TIMEOUT*60;
  $q = "SELECT * FROM picsmanager WHERE expires < $timeout AND action='temp'";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);

   foreach($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
       $q = sprintf("delete * from picsmanager where IMG_ID = %d", (int)$row['IMG_ID']);
//@unlink($uploadsDirectory1.$uploadFilename);
   }
```

}